# Why usage of end argument of print function changing the output time?

Tags: python

Maybe I wrote smth strange in a question title, I'l try to explain.
I'm trying to do password input as in linux-based systems (no symbols shows while you type).
I found one function that did it.

```
def getchar():
   import tty, termios, sys
   fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
   old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
   try:
      tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
      ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
   finally:
      termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
   return ch

pwd = ''

print('Type password:', end=' ') # HERE IS THE PROBLEM

while True:
    ch = getchar()
    if ch == '\r':
        break
    pwd += ch

print(pwd)
```

If I do not use `end` argument it looks like that:
[image]

But with `end` argument:[image]

Line 'Type password:' will appear after `while` loop end.
Why is this and what can I do?

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sys.stdout` is *line buffered*, which means that anything written to it is buffered up until a newline is seen.

Because you replaced the standard `end='\n'` with a space, no newline is seen yet and the buffer is not flushed. Set `flush=True` to force a buffer flush *anyway*:

```
print('Type password:', end=' ', flush=True)
```

Comment: Like buffered strings is not immutable?

Comment: @Aero: this has nothing to do with immutability; the buffer takes machine-level bytes, not Python objects anyway (usually buffers like these are handled in C code).